# Some of the Eloquent Javascript code doesn't want to run for me.

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the EJS resource along with CodeAcademy to try and learn Javascript however most of the code in Eloquent Javascript won't run properly for me and I feel like I'm not learning much from it at the moment which is disheartening because it's meant to be one of the best resources.

```
var currentNumber = 0;
while (currentNumber <= 12)
  currentNumber = currentNumber + 2;
```

This code above only prints out one number where I believe it should print numerous numbers before ending the loop. The for i = blah blah I++ version works but the while loop doesn't for some reason.

```
var result = 1;
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
  result = result * 2;
  counter = counter + 1;
}
show(result);
```

This code also doesn't work and says that 'show is not defined'. Is this because I'm doing it in the Firefox web console instead of the console in the web version? I'm currently using the PDF version. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It told you the right thing, show is not defined.....

Comment: As for `show()`, yes, it is not working because you're using the web console rather than the thing they've got on their page. `show()` is a function on that page that puts the result in a field (or something, I don't remember). A solution is just to use `console.log` instead of `show`.

Comment: Your first code block won't print anything out; there must be a `show()` or `log()` or something after it which you didn't include.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
var currentNumber = 0;
while (currentNumber <= 12)
  console.log( currentNumber = currentNumber + 2 );
```

which shows:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
```

Comment: try `console.log(currentNumber += 2)`

Comment: @randunel: yeah, that works, but i wanted to isolate the issue without confounding the problem...

Comment: I think you mean _compounding_... :)

Comment: @Andy: nope, i meant what i said. Confound (v): to mix up (something) with something else so that the individual elements become difficult to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no command "show" in javascript. To get something to print to the web console, use the command console.log() like so:

```
console.log(result);
```

Second, let's think about why your code is not printing out multiple times? What block of code is being executed every time we run through the while loop? Is the statement that prints out the current value within that block?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Eloquent JS is an interactive book which has its very own environment to run JS, so outside that environment some functions will not run. Like "show" won't run.

Use console.log instead of show in your second example. Console.log is like "show", but will run in IE, Firefox, Chrome console.

In the first example do the following:

```
var currentNumber = 0;
while (currentNumber <= 12) {
  currentNumber = currentNumber + 2; 
  console.log(currentNumber);
}
```

That's how you enclose two statements withing brackets to run with this while loop. The second statement ("console.log") will print the current value for currentNumber.